# Bootstrap Navbar slide on scroll not smooth

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, slide

I want my navbar to only show after scrolling. I've done that with JS but there's a "step" when it slides up or down. Here is the JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // hide .navbar first
    $(".navbar").hide();

    // fade in .navbar
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.navbar').slideDown(2000);
            } 
            else {
                $('.navbar').slideUp(2000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3dcg2ygw/

How can I get it smooth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the navbar has a minimum height, try this in your code:

```
.navbar {
    height: 97px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4nfq9kx/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a fade in jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // hide .navbar first
    $(".navbar").hide();

    // fade in .navbar
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.navbar').fadeIn().slideDown();
            } else {
                $('.navbar').fadeOut().slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
});
```